# navigate in hector map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I get a nav_msgs/ OccupancyGrid and can view it in rivz, all works fine.
But i have no idea if there is any package or node to navigate with that map.
I am using hector_mapping and a hokulu_laser to get the map.

Are there any packages or so in ros where this is already implemented or do you have a link to a tutorial about that topic and is there anywhere a detailed explanaishon about the OccupancyGrid ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38575/navigate-in-hector-map/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation). I don't imagine that navigation with an Occupancy Grid Map will be any different based on its orgin. An occupancy grid map is a map of fixed size containing

> An occupancy grid map represents the
> map as a field of random variables
> arranged in an evenly spaced grid.
> Each random variable is a binary and
> corresponds to the occupancy of the
> location it covers.

~ Probabilistic Robotics definition.

This means that the Occupancy of a space is a binary comparision (1 = occupied, 0 = empty). Hope this was helpful! Just try the navigation stack with your map.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1